# how to change the image size dynamically in asp repeater without store the image size in database

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net

i have the following repeater:

```
          <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptnewfeeds">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <div id="main" role="main" style="width: 1153px; margin-top: -105px; left: 105px; position: absolute;">

                            <ul id="tiles">
                                <li>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("image") %>'  />
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:Repeater>
```

code: -

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string select = "select image from UserProfileData where date>='2013-09-01'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, _connect());
        da.Fill(ds);
        rptnewfeeds.DataSource = ds;
        rptnewfeeds.DataBind();
```

now it is bind all `the images as same size` but i want to all images as `different size`

for example suppose now the 10 images has `width=200 and height=200`

```
now i want like 1st image has width=200 and height=300
2nd image has width=200 and height=283
3rd image has width=200 and height=230
...
... and so on
```

so how can i do this ?

how can i get the all random height of images in repeater ?

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Before databinding, add a column, in this example H for height to your dataset containing the height and you need.

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("H", typeof(int));
```

Fill this column for each row with the height you need. Either random or with some value you want.

In the repeater, databind to this new columns

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Height='<%#Eval("H") %>'
```

Same for width..

Comment: can you please explain with example ??

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. What height/width do you want to have?

Comment: i want height=200 and width=200

Comment: and height should change for other images

Comment: So, code that part into the extra column before you do rptnewfeeds.DataBind() and you will be fine

Comment: when i put ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("H", typeof(int)); after   rptnewfeeds.DataSource = ds; then it gives error - "Specified cast is not valid."